Jenkins isn't listening on ipv4 even after configuring it from ''/etc/default/jenkins''
I am using 24.04 LTS and trying to run jenkins. I have added
JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"
JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=9090 --httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0"
These lines in the jenkins configuration (/etc/default/jenkins) file, still not working.
I also allowed the port from ufw. Here is the ufw status-
9090                       ALLOW       Anywhere
9090/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
But when i run sudo netstat -tuln | grep 9090 it's showing tcp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::                    LISTEN*
I can't access jenkins web interface using the server's ipv4 address. What's going wrong? I searched online and tried chatgpt but couldn't find solution.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
